# ModelForm to OneToMany relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I need create the following relationship:

One "Rule" can have many users, but one user can be only one rule.

Using ForeignKey and a ModelForm, I get a select box to select just ONE user, but I want to select many users. It's not a ManyToMany relationship because  one user never can be more than one rule.

Here are my model definitions:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_(u'Nome do usuário'), max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(_('Senha'), max_length=20)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Rule(models.Model):
    ACTIONS = (
        ('liberate', 'Liberar'),
        ('block', 'Bloquear'),
    )

    users = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.CharField(_(u'Descrição'), max_length=30)
    extensions = models.TextField(_(u'Extensões'), blank=True)
    words = models.TextField(_(u'Palavras'), blank=True)
    domains = models.TextField(_(u'Domínios'), blank=True)
    time = models.TimeField(_(u'Horário'))
    action = models.CharField(_(u'Ação'), max_length=8, choices=ACTIONS)
```

Have some way of to do ir using a ModelForm?

Comment: Paste your model definitions. Though it does sound like you've just created the relation to the wrong model.

Answer (score 1):

> One "Rule" can have many users, but
>   one user can be only one rule.

To do this you need to move your foreign key into User. That way User A, B, and C could all choose Rule 1 but User A could never select two foreign keys to Rules since there is only one field.

To represent this a form look at [inline formsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) documentation.